# Best way to programmatically save a webpage to a Static HTML File

Tags: python, html, css, html-parsing

The more research I do, the more grim the outlook becomes.

I am trying to Flat Save, or Static Save a webpage with Python. This means merging all the styles to inline properties, and changing all links to absolute URLs.

I've tried nearly every free conversion website, api, and even libraries on github. None are that impressive. The best python implementation I could find for flattening styles is https://github.com/davecranwell/inline-styler. I adapted that slightly for Flask, but the generated file isn't that great. Here's how it looks:

[image]

Obviously, it should look better. Here's what it should look like:

https://dzwonsemrish7.cloudfront.net/items/3U302I3Y1H0J1h1Z0t1V/Screen%20Shot%202012-12-19%20at%205.51.44%20PM.png?v=2d0e3d26

It seems like a neverending struggle dealing with Malformed html, unrecognized CSS properties, Unicode errors, etc. So does anyone have a suggestion on a better way to do this? I understand I can go to file -> save in my local browser, but when I am trying to do this en mass, and extract a particular xpath that's not really viable.

It looks like Evernote's web clipper uses iFrames, but that seems more complicated than I think it should be. But at least the clippings look decent on Evernote.

Comment: Maybe use iMacros or Selenium to write a macro to literally do the `File...Save As` from your browser.  Might just be simpler for now than figuring it out in Python.

Comment: maybe take the whole css and put it between <style></style> tags on the document itself. if a whole stylesheet gets converted to inline styles obv all specifity is gone, so its bound not to work.

Comment: Thanks for the responses so far. 

I really want to create a snippet of one Xpath on the page, and I'd like the styles to be preserved. The only way I can think to do that is with inline styles. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: Did you try jsdom with node.js instead of python? You can use `getComputedStyle` and apply it to the HTML tag

Answer (score 3):

After walking away for a while, I managed to install a ruby library that flattens the CSS much much better than anything else I've used. It's the library behind the very slow web interface here http://premailer.dialect.ca/

Thank goodness they released the source on Github, it's the best hands down.
https://github.com/alexdunae/premailer

It flattens styles, creates absolute urls, works with a URL or string, and can even create plain text email templates. Very impressed with this library.

### Update Nov 2013

I ended up writing my own bookmarklet that works purely client side. It is compatible with Webkit and FireFox only. It recurses through each node and adds inline styles then sends the flattened HTML to the clippy.in API to save to the user's dashboard.

[Client Side Bookmarklet](https://clippy.in/static/js/script.js)

Comment: Sounds great - looking forward to checking it out

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like inline styles might be a deal-breaker for you, but if not, I suggest taking another look at Evernote Web Clipper. The desktop app has an Export HTML feature for web clips. The output is a bit messy as you'd expect with inline styles, but I've found the markup to be a reliable representation of the saved page.

Regarding inline vs. external styles, for something like this I don't see any way around inline if you're doing a lot of pages from different sites where class names would have conflicting style rules.

You mentioned that Web Clipper uses iFrames, but I haven't found this to be the case for the HTML output. You'd likely have to embed the static page as an iFrame if you're re-publishing on another site (legally I assume), but otherwise that shouldn't be an issue.

Some automation would certainly help so you could go straight from the browser to the HTML output, and perhaps for relocating the saved images to a single repo with updated src links in the HTML. If you end up working on something like this, I'd be grateful to try it out myself.