# Algorithm to save an exact static copy of a webpage with links and everything, so that it opens as original

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I am trying to make a bookmark app. I want the user be able to save a particular section of the webpage.

I am thinking about saving some coordinates from the original target webpage with its complete static copy. So that when the user opens the saved copy, he gets the exact duplicate of the original webpage with the coordinates of the selected section. I need to save the copy because the content on the webpage can change over time.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13962719/best-way-to-programmatically-save-a-webpage-to-a-static-html-file) was a little helpful. I tried premailer online tool at their site but it could not capture heavy js sites. I am using node.js at the backend.

Please guide me in the right direction. Thanks!

Comment: Try phantomjs to load the page. You can capture and store all requested resources, if you need an exact copy. However, when "reloading" the copy you might need to fake the current time as well, and maybe some other global conditions that could have changed.

Comment: I wouldn't try to store a dynamic (heavy js) "exact duplicate" - there are too many ways this could go wrong at "replay time". I'd try to extract the DOM at the suggested coordinates, and only store that (maybe including css and images).

Comment: Thanks Bergi. But these days most of the sites use a lot of js. Ignoring this would not make this app future proof.

Comment: I didn't say you should ignore it. However, for a "static copy" you don't need the interactivity that had been in the page when it was stored, do you? You just need to snapshot the "current state". Or what exactly should your "bookmark app" be used for?

Comment: be wary of copyright issues

Comment: Sorry my bad. Js wont be needed after the page is loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's consider the two cases of this problem:

1. You want to save only explicitly listed files.
2. You want to save explicitly listed and implicitly loaded (ie via JS-generated URLs + AJAX) files.

The first case is pretty straightforward to implement with an HTML parser. I'm not going to go into that, because you mention 'heavy js sites', which seems to imply that you're interested in the second case.

@Bergi (first comment on the question) has the right idea: load the page and then store everything that is downloaded. However, you then have to have some way to open it as a static HTML page. This *could* be done by rewriting all AJAX calls into raw function calls. (SPOILER: this is a really bad way to do it)

For example:

```
$.get(url, data, callback);
```

would need to be transformed into:

```
callback(response);
```

This is no trivial task. JavaScript is an extremely flexible language. There are so many ways to implement an AJAX call that it really wouldn't be feasible to rewrite the JS like this in such a way that'd work for all JS code. Even worse, code may depend on the AJAX call not returning immediately (bad form and a terrible idea, but this is *the internet* after all).

The problem can be simplified if you're willing to move away from a standalone static HTML solution. You could implement a chrome or firefox extension (or a standalone application) that saves all the required data into a cache and then -- when loading the saved version -- forces it to pull from the cache or uses a faked `XMLHttpRequest` object to prevent querying the remote server. You could also fake the date/time and other external state variables in this environment.

The way I would handle this is to take an existing customizable renderer (eg Chrome, Firefox) and implement an extension as described above.

Regardless, I'd seriously reconsider the necessity of such a solution. Could something simpler (screenshot with HTML image-map links that's loaded in the browser?) solve the problem? I feel like the problem *probably* doesn't need such a complicated solution, but not many details are given about your problem so I may well be wrong.

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful. Chrome and firefox extensions will make it easy to gather the data from the webpage necessary to as it is display it again. Can you give me some technical terms I should research this through. Evernote does it. I am looking for that similar kind of technology.

Comment: No, you shouldn't try to rewrite the js - that just *will* go wrong. Instead, fake/mock the underlying API (that is, `XMLHttpRequest` in the js environment, or even the HTTP stack in the browser if you have access to that).

Comment: @Bergi: you will notice that I recommend *not* going down that route. I bring it up and shoot it down specifically because it *will* be suggested at some point. Best to get it out of the way with a few reasons of why to avoid doing it. Faking `XMLHttpRequest` is more or less what I suggested, though your phrasing is better.

Comment: OK, but maybe you should rephrase "*This means rewriting all AJAX calls into raw function calls.*" into something like "This *could* be done by …"

Comment: I found a chrome extension by the name of SingleFile which saves the page as .html file. I am gonna look into it. Thanks for the tip.